# New Reason for Rejecting Edits

Tags: feature-request, edits

Question : [Selecting data from multiple rows and insert it into a column](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/73288/selecting-data-from-multiple-rows-and-insert-it-into-a-column).

[@LenHart](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/39278/lennart) [posted an answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/73296/877)

[**Someone else**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/44838/daniel-hutmacher) tried to add to his answer with this edit

```
Edit: The T-SQL (SQL Server) syntax uses CROSS APPLY to perform the same task, i.e.:

    SELECT x.name, y.address
    FROM temp x 
    CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (x.name, x.city),
                         (x.name, x.phone_no),
                         (x.name, x.pincode)) AS y(name, address) 

CROSS APPLY in SQL Server also often generates more effective execution plans than a bunch of union operators, so it's definitely worth a try.
```

I had rejected it with the reason `Should be posted as a separate answer`.

Would it be worth it to add this as a standard reason for rejecting edits ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. This was a good edit suggestion. Having multiple answers that address part of the question is not preferable to having one good, collaboratively-improved answer. This is a wiki site, after all.

Comment: OK that makes sense. Thank You

Answer (score 7):

I have to disagree with the currently accepted answer.
This is a Wiki site, but there is more than one possible, valid answer for most of the more complex questions. It helps to keep *different* answers from multiple authors ***separate***:

- To see *when* each was posted easily, without having to study the edit history.
- To have *separate* votes on multiple alternatives, so we can see which solution is more popular (taking the date of the post into account).
- In extreme cases to flag / close / delete just *that* answer.
- To attribute each answer to a specific author. Regulars - most probably including *you* (the reader) - learn to interpret answers better, knowing the background of the author a bit.
  For instance, I can understand why somebody choses a certain syntax variant, given that 90% of his answers are for RDBMS XY.

If all parties agree on a single, cooperative answer, that's perfectly fine, of course. We would see comments indicating as much ...